# How to add xslt debug feature to RSA editor

Tags: xslt, eclipse-plugin, saxon, ibm-rad

I'm using RSA 8.0.0 editor and I'd like to debug an xslt file using F6 etc buttons same like java file. Can any one let me know the process to get this feature?

Also, right clicked on xslt file -> Run As -> Run configurations -> Processor tab -> am seeing only 'IBM Processor for XSLT 2.0' in the processor drop down. How can I get another vendor specific (say saxon) processor here?

Can any one please help me on priority?

Answer (score 0):

From the Saxon perspective, I'm afraid I can't help you all that much. RSA (Rational Software) as I understand it is an IBM product, so it wouldn't be surprising if the only XSLT processor they support is their own. As far as debugging is concerned, integrating a debugger with Saxon is a fairly substantial project. I know that oXygen and Stylus Studio have integrated debuggers for Saxon, and I think there may also be offerings in IntelliJ and EditIX, but I'm not sure of their status.